# What's code snippet of tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood in latest tensorflow version 2.8

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

The below functions existed in Tensorflow 1.5 which is currently deprecated.

What's the corresponding code for the function:

> tf.contrib.crf.crf_log_likelihood()

> tf.contrib.crf.viterbi_decode()

in the latest Tensorflow 2.8 version?

Answer (score 0):

These both functions are now available under `Tensorflow` `Addons` package.

You can access these functions using code below:

```
!pip install tensorflow_addons     #to install tensorflow_addons package
import tensorflow_addons as tfa  

tfa.text.crf_log_likelihood()
tfa.text.viterbi_decode()
```

Please check [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/text/crf_log_likelihood) link for more details.